# convert 2d array to pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to teach myself C, so I wrote a program to keep records for a gradebook! In my effort to learn pointers, I'm trying to convert one of my beginning projects of arrays to pointers. I want to convert my 2d array to pointers. Below is my original program to with the 2d array, and below that is my attempt to convert it to 2d pointer array.

**ORIGINAL PROGRAM**

```
int numberPeople, choice, i, j;
char people[15][3][100];

printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min %d, max %d): ", 5, 15);

scanf("%d", &numberPeople);

while ((numberPeople < 5) || (numberPeople > 15)) {
    printf("\nNumber not in specified range, try again.\n");
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min %d, max %d): ", 5, 15);
    scanf("%d", &numberPeople);
}

printf("\n");

while ((getchar()) != '\n'); // flush the return (and anything else) after the number input above

printf("Enter the first name, last name, and grade (put a space in between each): \n");

for (i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
    char tempArr[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH];

    fgets(tempArr, MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);

    char *token = strtok(tempArr, " ");

    for (j = 0; j < DATA_FIELDS && token != NULL; j++) {
        strncpy(people[i][j], token, MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");
    }

}
```

**ATTEMPT AT 2D ARRAY -> POINTER**

```
int numberPeople, choice, i, j;
char* people;


printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min %d, max %d): ", 5, 15);

scanf("%d", &numberPeople);

people = (char*)(malloc(numberPeople*DATA_FIELDS*sizeof(char)));

while ((numberPeople < 5) || (numberPeople > 15)) {
    printf("\nNumber not in specified range, try again.\n");
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min %d, max %d): ", 5, 15);
    scanf("%d", &numberPeople);
}

printf("\n");

while ((getchar()) != '\n'); // flush the return (and anything else) after the number input above

printf("Enter the first name, last name, and grade (put a space in between each): \n");

for (i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
    char* tempArr;

    fgets(tempArr, 100, stdin); // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 address=0x0

    char *token = strtok(tempArr, " ");

    for (j = 0; j < 3 && token != NULL; j++) {
        strncpy(people, token, 50);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \r\n");
    }

}
```

During the person input step is when it breaks. It works for the first entry, but then it hits a breakpoint (I'm using Xcode), and it reads "EXC_BAD_ACCESS", and I'm not too sure what this means, any tips would help, thanks!

Comment: First thing: `numberPeople` is uninitialized or is zero, but used in `malloc`

Comment: Second thing: your first example is an array of arrays of arrays. A pointer to the underlying element type of the most dominant dimension should be your goal when moving that to dynamic storage: i.e. `char (*people)[3][100];`, assuming it is the `15` that you're targeting as variadic.

Comment: Oh wow, rookie mistake. I just EDITED and moved the numberPeople further down so that now it has a value, thanks! @EugeneSh.

Comment: I'll take note of that. thanks! @WhozCraig Is it possible to make this program with nothing but pointers (no arrays whatsoever)? This is what I'm trying to accomplish. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't. If you can manage this with a single pointer to a dynamic array of arrays of arrays, I'd seriously think about why to do it any other way. Most of the time, software engineering is about doing what you *should*; not what you *can*.  Dynamic arrays of pointers to dynamic arrays of pointers to dynamic arrays leans heavily to the latter, and not the former. That said, you can do it, sure, but you had better be *more* comfortable with dynamic management that this seems to indicate.

Comment: @WhozCraig alright, cool. This is some good advice and I'll take note of it. As I said in my original post, I'm new to pointers and I'm still learning my limitations. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Don't move to multi dimensions until you see single-dimension management in your sleep. You're just asking for a festival of seg-faults in a debugger if you move too fast. Best of luck.

Comment: In C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) no not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Therefore that expression in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult.... 3) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  (5, 15, 100)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, via an enum or #define statements.  Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) use meaningful variable names.  The names should indicate usage or content (or better, both).  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: suggest moving the call to `malloc()` after getting a final value for `numberPeople` contains a final value.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert to all pointers but I wouldn't recommend it. Here's an example:

```
char ***people = malloc(sizeof(*people) * 15);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    people[i] = malloc(sizeof(*people[i]) * 3);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        people[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*people[i][j]) * 100);
    }
}
```

This would re-create the array `char people[15][3][100];`. As you can see, it's messy. Plus, you have to free all that mem when you are done.

I cleaner way would be to use a struct:

```
struct Student {
    char firstName[100];
    char lastName[100];
    char grade[100];
};
struct Student people[15];
```

This will set aside as much memory as the array. You could also dynamically allocate as many students as needed:

```
struct Student *people = malloc(sizeof(*people) * 20);
```

That will get 20 students. You can access them using array notation:

```
printf("%s %s %s", people[0].firstName, people[0].lastName, people[0].grade);
```

And you only need to call `free` once.

Answer (score 0):

this pair of lines is not correct:

```
char* tempArr; 
fgets(tempArr, 100, stdin);
```

the declaration of the pointer: `tempArr` is not allocating any actual memory to contain the line read by the the call to `fgets()` Suggest:

```
#define MAX_INPUT_LEN (100)
 ... 
char tempArr[MAX_INPUT_LEN]; 
fgets( tempArr, MAX_INPUT_LEN, stdin );
```

Also, the returned value from the call to `fgets()` should be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.